# Oracle Best-Buyer-Customer is Wholesale or Retail buyer

Tags: oracle-11g, query, data-warehouse

I have data warehouse with Fact table Orders, and CustomerDimension, and TimeDimention, and BookDimension.

```
CREATE TABLE DIM_CUSTOMER(
    DIMCUSTID NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY, 
    CustId    NUMBER(4)   NOT NULL,
    L_Name    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    F_Name    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    City      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Country   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE TDIM_TIME(
    TIMEID   DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    DAY      NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    MONTH    NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    QUARTER  NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    SEMESTER NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    YEAR     NUMBER(5) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE TDIM_BOOK(
    ISBN        NUMBER  PRIMARY KEY,
    TITLE       VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    EDITIONNO   NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    PRICE       NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    AUTHORS     VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
    PUB_NAME    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CITY        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    COUNTRY     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE TFACT_ORDER(
    FACTORDERID NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    DIMCUSTID   NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    ISBN        NUMBER    NOT NULL,
    TIMEID      DATE      NOT NULL,
    QUANTITY    NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    PRICE       NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_TDIMBOOK FOREIGN KEY (ISBN) 
    REFERENCES hwu.TDIM_BOOK(ISBN),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TDIMCUST FOREIGN KEY (DIMCUSTID) 
    REFERENCES hwu.TDIM_CUSTOMER(DIMCUSTID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TDIMTIME FOREIGN KEY (TIMEID) 
    REFERENCES hwu.TDIM_TIME(TIMEID)
)
```

I need to find if my Best-Customer (Who had buy the most quantity of Books) had orders a lot of orders with low price (Retail Buyer), or he had order a few orders with high price (Wholesale Buyer).

How can I achieve this in Oracle?

Edit:

Lots of orders : 500 order in year

Few orders: 10 order in year

High price: 50000$ or more; for each order of him

Low price: 100$ or lower; for each order of him

Comment: How many is "lot of/few orders"? How much is "low/high price"? Define the problem and you will have the solution right away.

Comment: I've edited my question; and add those details